# Running a .NET program off aspx files

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I have been doing web development for some time now but am super new to .NET applications. I have a directory of other directories, each of which holds a .aspx file and images (occasionally there is a web.config file):

[Here is an example of the file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5cA3.png)

My question now is - how/can I run these files so I can make edits to the HTML/CSS on my local machine and see the results on localhost? Am I missing any files or do I need to be on Windows?

Any help/explanation you can provide would be much appreciated!!

Environment:

- Mac OS 10.15
- VS for Mac 8.3.11
- Dotnet 3.1.100

Comment: create a project of asp.net core and migrate code to .cs from aspx, NOTE: aspx don't run on dotnet core you can use cshtml with Razor

Comment: You need to host those files under Internet Information Server or any compatible web server that can host .aspx files. These files are "Active Server Pages" and uses one of the script languages installed, usually either VBScript or JavaScript. Since these doesn't compile to anything, if you have all the files, once you have them hosted you should be able to modify them just fine, they're just regular text files after all. Since you mention Mac OS, I don't know if there are any web server software that will work for you but the details in my comment should get you started looking.